# Regex to add characters to beginning of line

Tags: java, regex

I'm using Java and I have a string that could potentially be one of the following formats:

```
1234
XX1234
XX 1234
XX (some variable amount of spaces) 1234
```

And I want to output

```
#XX1234
```

No matter the input.
I can't quite figure out how to handle the first case, where the XX is lacking. I know I can locate the prefix if it's there with **^XX\s***.

Is there a way to do this formatting with a single regex and string replace?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/rH1qH9/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex. You need to make group `XX` optional using `?`

```
^((?:XX)?\s*1234)$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rH1qH9/2)**